# VLOOKUP using a date as the search key (but ignoring the day)

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, string-formatting, vlookup

The range A2:A contains months where each month uses the first day of the month. Users are allowed to input any day within that month when entering their data. The range of user input dates is defined by the named range "EAR_DATES_RNG". Each month has a corresponding summary of earnings for that month.

So here is an example of what this might look like:

```
User Input:
1/11/2017 - $100
2/9/2017 - $250
3/21/2017 - $500

Summary:
1/1/2017 - $100
2/1/2017 - $250
3/1/2017 - $500
```

Previously, I had a note forcing users to also use the first day of the month for their inputs, however I would like to free that up. However, this has caused my VLOOKUP() to stop working as it was previously using the summary date to find the corresponding user input:

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&" "&$A$1,{EAR_DATES_RNG&" "&EAR_NAMES_RNG,EAR_AMOUNTS_RNG},2,false),"")), IF(COUNT(A2:A)=0,1,COUNT(A2:A)),1)`

How could I instead tell VLOOKUP to ignore the day of the month?

Or maybe there is a way I could somehow convert the user input dates to the first of the month using EOMONTH() tricks when I create the array in the formula, however maybe the fact that I use a named range will pose another problem for me to overcome.

I can however, see a solution already that would require a helper column that converts all the dates in EAR_DATES_RNG and then the formula creates the array using that converted range instead, but I would like to avoid a helper column if possible.

Appreciate any help I can get with this!

Screenshot examples:

**OUTPUT:**

[[image: VLOOKUP SHEET1]

**INPUT:**

[image: USER IMPORT SHEET]

January and March user inputs do not use the first day of the month, while February and April do. So as a result, in the 1st image, January and March values are blank in Column C, while February and April are showing up.

My VLOOKUP() is in Column C of the first image and is supposed to be grabbing the corresponding values of Column G in the second image.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 I don't think it would be possible as the sheet uses data that is imported from another sheet that the user should have. I have not tested that behavior yet. But I'll add the some screenshots, maybe that'll help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TEXT(A2:A, "m/1/e")*1&" "&$A$1, 
 {EAR_DATES_RNG&" "&EAR_NAMES_RNG, EAR_AMOUNTS_RNG}, 2, 0))), 
 IF(COUNT(A2:A)=0, 1, COUNT(A2:A)), 1)
```

or:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&" "&$A$1, 
 {TEXT(EAR_DATES_RNG, "m/1/e")*1&" "&EAR_NAMES_RNG, EAR_AMOUNTS_RNG}, 2, 0))), 
 IF(COUNT(A2:A)=0, 1, COUNT(A2:A)), 1)
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. Although if I understood your changes correctly, I think you did it the other way around; all the A2:A values are already set to the first of the month and it is the user input dates that need to be changed. So in the context of your answer, it would be something like ```TEXT(EAR_DATES_RNG, "m/1/e")*1```

Comment: I should clarify, since both images use the A column for dates:

```EAR_DATES_RNG = 2nd Image Column A``` and ```A2:A = 1st Image Column A```

Comment: @dan  hard to tell without a chance to test it out and confirm it. try the 2nd one

Comment: I just realized that even without the second sheet you could replace the IMPORTRANGE() formula and just use your own sample data, my bad on that! But, I can confirm that the second equation is working!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script version of the function you want.

```
function firstOfTheMonth() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //Gets the values of column A until the last row with data
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1);

  //Changes the date values of column A into MM-YYYY-1
  // You need to define your TimeZone on Utilities.formatDate(new Date(y), "YOUR TIMEZONE HERE", "MM-1-yyyy")
  var val = range.getValues();
  var newval = val.map(x => x.map(y => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(y), "GMT+8", "MM-1-yyyy")));

  console.log(newval);
  range.setValues(newval); 
}
```

You can manually add the function on an onEdit Trigger so that the function will automatically run whenever an edit is made on the spreadsheet.

[image]

**Before:**

[image]

**After the script was ran:**

[image]

**Reference:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)

Comment: A great idea! Although I think my goal is to ultimately not actually mess with the original input by the user and have the date interpreted as the first day of the month within the formula itself.

Comment: I think @player0 just posted a corrected version of his original idea of using the TEXT() function which appears to be working now, thanks!